# Why is my /books/book POST endpoint returning unauthorized

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am learning Spring Security and am trying to make a simple web service that holds the title of a book. I am trying to implement my security so that everyone can use GET on my /books/book endpoint and authorized users can POST to /books/book. For some reason my POST endpoint is saying that my user is authorized even through i have added the authentication header with the correct credentials.

I have been looking at different examples online but I just can't seem to find out where my mistake was.

My UserDetailsService holds one user named batman that has a USER role that is required for POSTing to /books/book

```
@Component
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String string) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("batman").password("pass").roles("ADMIN", "USER").build();

    }

}
```

My SecurityConfig should allow a GET request for unauthorized users to /book/books. This part works.

A POST method to /book/books should be allowed only for authorized users. This part does not work and is returning unauthorized for everyone.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CustomSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().and().cors().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/books/book").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/books/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }

}
```

My BookController looks like this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/books")
public class BookController {
   @Autowired
   private BookService bookService;

   @GetMapping("/book")
   public ResponseEntity<Object> getAll() {
       return new ResponseEntity<>(bookService.getAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
   }

   @PostMapping("/book")
   public ResponseEntity<Object> add(@RequestBody Book book) {
       bookService.addBook(book);
       return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
   }
}
```

My BookService

```
@Service
public class BookService {

    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    public Collection getAll() {
        return bookRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void addBook(Book book) {
        bookRepository.save(book);
    }

    public void deleteBook(Long id) {
        bookRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    public void updateBook(Long id, Book book){
        bookRepository.findById(id).map((entry) -> {
            entry.setTitle(book.getTitle());
            bookRepository.save(book);
            return entry;
        });
    }

}
```

My BookRepository

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long>{
    List<Book> findBookByTitle(String title);
}
```

My Book class

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String title;
}
```

The expected result is unauthorized GET request to /books/book and authorized POST request to /book/books

Comment: I am sending the token via postman and i use basic authentication. The result i get has a http status of 403 which means it is unauthorized.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Spring Boot?

One thing that seems strange to me is  that you are not doing anything with your CustomUserDetailsService.

try adding to CustomSecurityConfig

```
@Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    }
```

Comment: The solution does not work.I am autowiring the customUserDetaulsService so that Spring IOC handles the object for me automaticly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the version of my Spring dependencies. When I upgraded the version the problem no longer occured.